# Book about a woman lost in a maze with doors that lead to different living places

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a title/author of a book, the first in a series, which I read perhaps 25 years ago.

The book was about a maze/labyrinth with doors.  The doors lead to other inhabitants with their own living environment(perhaps portals).  There is a dark, unknown man who is the overseer/caretaker.  A young woman is trapped in the labyrinth and is opening doors trying to find a way out.  The inhabitants  in the doors are not friendly.  The young woman is afraid of the man, who seems to be trying to lead her somewhere. She keeps running from him.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like [Guardian's Key](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/317499.Guardian_s_Key) by Anne Logston.

Dara has entered the Crystal Keep to gain the magic she needs to win her lover.  As soon as she enters the keep she meets the Guardian of the Oracle, Lord Vanian:

> She hadn't expected the Guardian of the Oracle to be so young; he
>   seemed scarcely older than herself, although his eyes... well, his
>   eyes knew something old.  His long, wispy hair was black as a raven's feathers, with the same bluish sheen, and his clothes were of silk as dark, and his black leather boots were supple and shiny.  His skin was pale, and his eyes were ebony like the night sky with no stars to light it.

Dara receives from Vanian a key, which will open doors in the Crystal Keep and allow her to search for the Oracle.  She then finds that there are a *lot* of doors in the almost never-ending corridor she finds herself in, and while the doorways are only a few paces apart, each is a portal leading to an area varying from a room, to a section of swamp to a village and surrounding fields.

Dara meets Granny Good, who provides some helpful advice in exchange for a mouthful of water, and a monkey-like creature called Gespry who accompanies her as she starts searching door after door.  Most of the other beings she encounters are hostile, as stated by the OP.  Vanian appears from time to time to taunt her as she continues her quest and uses his magic to impersonate Dara's lover to seduce her.

All of the above happens in the first four chapters - needless to say, much is not as it initially seems.

Regarding the book being part of a series, the only direct sequel is [Exile](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/232286.Exile).  However, I recall that there are references in the books to make it clear that this is the same world as the [Shadow](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/232279.Shadow) and Dagger series by the same author.

Answer (score 1):

Another story that comes to my mind is "**Jirel Meets Magic**" by **Catherine Lucille** (C.L.) **Moore**, [published in 1935 in Weird Tales](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56923).

While chasing Giraud, a wizard she wants to kill, the eponymous character, Jirel of Joiry, jumps through a portal and enters another dimension. Later in the story, she enters a tower where another sorceress (Giraud's mistress) lives: the tower's lobby opens on several doors that lead to other environments, some of them even dangerous.

This blog has [a short summary of the story](https://adventuresfantastic.com/jirel-meets-magic-on-c-l-moores-birthday/).